# Sequelize OP -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'like' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my project, i'd like to search many subways have a certain keyword.

So, I use **Op** in Sequelize, but it returned `TypeError: Cannot read property 'like' of undefined`.

The way I initialized the sequelize object is as follows.

```
// root/models/index.js

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

db.sequelize = sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

And, I initialized and used the Op object like this

```
const { Subway } = require("../../models");
const sequelize = require("../../models").sequelize;
const Op = sequelize.Op;

const list = await Subway.findAll({
            where: {
                station_name_kr: {
                    [Op.like]: '%' + req.params.filter + '%',
                },
            },
            attributes: [
                'idx',
                'station_line',
                'station_name_kr'
            ],
        });
```

But it didn't work....

Could you tell me what is the problem?

---

**Edit 1**

```
// models/subway.js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = class Subway extends Sequelize.Model {
    static init(sequelize){
        return super.init({
            idx: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            station_code: {
                type: Sequelize.CHAR(20),
            },
            station_name_kr: {
                type: Sequelize.CHAR(20),
                allowNull: false,
            },
            station_name_en: {
                type: Sequelize.CHAR(30),
            },
            station_line: {
                type: Sequelize.CHAR(10),
            },
            outside_code: {
                type: Sequelize.CHAR(10),
            },
        }, {
            sequelize,
            timestamps: true,
            underscored: true,
            paranoid: true,
            modelName: 'subway',
            tableName: 'Subway',
            charset: 'utf8',
            collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: where is the file associating Subway with the connection?

Comment: I just edited my post with Subway file! @iwaduarte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are mistaking two things.

*First one:*
**S**equelize object from requiring library.

*Second one:*
**s**equelize connection from "instantiating" the **S**equelize Object.

Note the upper case and lower case (**s**)(**S**)equelize because they represent two distinct objects.

Below what you are trying to do is access the connection and from there the Operator (Op) property. It is not going to work. The sequelize **connection** does **NOT** have it.

```
const sequelize = require("../../models").sequelize; 
const Op = sequelize.Op;
```

To be able to access you should do the following:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = sequelize.Op;
```

That is why your answer "works". But that answer is not why it works.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry for late. Your answer is perfectly worked for me!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Oh the answer was very simple...

I just initialize a **Op** object like this.

```
const Op = require("sequelize").Op;
```

Then, I could use the Op object with like, or , and etc...

Comment: This is not the answer btw. Your code already did that.

Comment: I don't know well about Sequelize and Op, but this answer worked for me in this post....

Comment: I will give you a proper answer so you don't get confused anymore.